# how to get full url if it contains using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Can i get full url if the url starts with http://google.com** . here is my code

```
<div id="gettingdynamic">
    <a href="http://google.com?somedynamicparamenter">clickhere</a>
</div>
```

here every front of the code  it will come `http://google.com` after that i will get dynamic parameter so  what i want means when this url `http://google.com` contains in div i should get full url with parameter using jquery

Comment: Honestly is not clear what you ask.. try to clarify the question

Comment: actually i want to get full url if that url matches starting with http://google.com

Comment: yes i tried but i was not able to retrieve full url and i am new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

you could use the jquery attribute selector

```
$("#gettingdynamic a[href*='http://google.com']")
```

this selector returns all links within gettingdynamic which their href attribute start with http://google.com

for your code

```
$("#gettingdynamic a[href*='http://google.com']").attr("href") 
return "http://google.com?somedynamicparamenter"
```

if you have many links that start with http://google

```
$("#gettingdynamic a[href*='http://google.com']").each(function( index ) {
  console.log( this.href );
});
```

Comment: did you understand my questing it starts with http://google.com there will extra parameters for that which come from that here's the sample http://google.com?id=4 but for every url http://google.com will be there but iwant remaing url also

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery filter to get what you need:
http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```js
$("#gettingdynamic a[href]").filter(function(idx,elem){
    return jQuery(elem).attr("href").search(/^http:\/\/(www\.)?google\.com(\/|\?)/i) > -1;
}).attr('href');
```

and obviously for many items:

```js
$("#gettingdynamic a[href]").filter(function(idx,elem){
        return jQuery(elem).attr("href").search(/^http:\/\/(www\.)?google\.com(\/|\?)/i) > -1;
    }).each(function( idx ){
    console.log( this.href );
});
```

This basically says: Get all anchor (a) elements that are decendants of an element with an id of "gettingdynamic". Filter the returned results to only include those whose "href" attribute starts with (* means anything can exist after this point):

- http://www.google.com/*
- https://www.google.com/*
- http://google.com/*
- https://google.com/*
- http://www.google.com?*
- https://www.google.com?*
- http://google.com?*
- https://google.com?*

**UPDATE**

If you only want it to return the URL like "google.com?..." you can use this:

```
$("#gettingdynamic a[href]").filter(function(idx,elem){
        return jQuery(elem).attr("href").search(/^http:\/\/(www\.)?google\.com(\/|\?)/i) > -1;
    }).each(function( idx ){
    console.log( this.href.replace(/^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?/i, "") );
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Using jquery you can use this:

```
var url = $('#gettingdynamic a').attr('href');
var pattern = new RegExp('^https?://google.com'); 
//remove s? if you dont want to match https://google.com

if (pattern.test(url)) {
    // Use url here
    alert(url);
}
```

Comment: this is not correct i have bulk anchor on that div so i want if in anchor on staring href link http://google.com url matches i should get the full url.

Comment: Attempting to answer a question without understanding it is grounds for immediate voting in the downwards direction.